# IOS AppDelegate Variable in controller or token

Tags: ios, swift

im totally {fresh/beginner} app developer please bear with me if im asking any stupid question.

I trying to show token on my story board when my app runs. if you check my code. i already created delegates variable `var tokenVal = ""` when i run the app i do not get any value on my story board although, its printing token in console.

2nd issue its showing warnings although its compiling and running.

here is my problem AppDelegate.swift code

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var tokenVal = ""
    var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    registerPushNotifications()

    return true
}


func registerPushNotifications() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationType() {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}




func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }

    tokenVal = token
    print(token)
}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Registration failed!")
}


func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

ViewController.swift Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TokenLb: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tokenVarVal: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        //let aVariable = appDelegate.
        let bVariable = appDelegate.tokenVal
        tokenVarVal.text = bVariable
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image: Xcode Show these warnings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple matter of the order of operations. The app delegate's `tokenVal` is being set *after* the view controller's `viewDidLoad` runs.

(In general, using one class's property as a "drop" for another class to pick up a value later on is a clumsy strategy. If the other class needs this value, *give* the value *to* the other class.)

Comment: sir thanks for your vote & answer as i told you im new i don't know so many things thats why im here to seek help from guru's just like you. i have very limited  knowledge. trying to get some more. Thanks again ...

Comment: Make a new project using Apple's Master-Detail app template. Look at how MasterViewController _sends_ a value to DetailViewController by saying `controller.detailItem = object`. Now look at how DetailViewController is configured to respond so that _no matter when_ this happens — before or after `viewDidLoad` — the interface is updated.